# C# Underscore in httpContent

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

The APIKey of Rally begins with an underscore. While trying to post it, I am getting "Bad Request". Underscore cannot be removed from API Key since it is generated by Rally and Rally does not authorize, if underscore is absent.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ArtifactUUID", "ID1"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserUUID", "ID2"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("zuul_key",  "**APIKey begins with underscore**")
    };

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
var response = client.PostAsync("https://rally1.rallydev.com/notifications/api/v2/watch", content).Result;
```

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is in underscore? Probably, it is just a server response on your successfully authorized, but incorrectly built request.

Comment: If I remove the underscore, I get the response back as "Unauthorized". If I add the underscore, I get the response as "Bad Request". So I am deducing that problem is because of underscore.

Comment: Are you supposed to pass in the raw key, or encode it somehow (base64, for example)?  Just a thought.

Comment: @AriRoth I haven't thought about it, however, let me give it a try

Comment: I concur with @YeldarKurmangaliyev. I'd be willing to bet you got past authentication and the 400 response is an unrelated problem. Your logic about getting a different error when you took away the underscore is flawed - you almost certainly got an unauthorized error because you changed the key to an invalid one.